# Python Classes with Loops: Bank Accounts

Tags: python, class, loops, input

I'm having a huge issue and I really don't know what's wrong with this code I wrote, it definitely has something to do with the inputs I set up for my input file but i'm at a wall and I truly don't know how to proceed

I'm getting a name error for the inputs but this is how the book shows me how to set up the first Deposit. The input file is below the main program.

My question is, does anyone know what is wrong with the inputs I set out in the main? They seem to be correct but I keep getting a NameError: ABC123 is not defined for every change I try to put out.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, getbankaccount, inputAmount=0):
        self.__balance = inputAmount
        self.__numDeposits = 0
        self.__numWithdrawals = 0
        self.__totalDeposits = 0
        self.__totalWithdrawals = 0
        self.__getbankaccount=getbankaccount

    def getBalance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def getNumDeposits(self):
        return self.__numDeposits

    def getNumWithdrawals(self):
        return self.__numWithdrawals

    def getTotalDeposits(self):
        return self.__totalDeposits

    def getTotalWithdrawals(self):
        return self.__totalWithdrawals

    def getbankaccount(self):
        return self.__getbankaccount

    def Deposit(self,amount):
        self.__balance = self.__balance + amount
        self.__numDeposits = self.__numDeposits + 1
        self.__totalDeposits = self.__totalDeposits + amount
        return self.__balance

    def Withdrawal(self,amount):
        if (self.__balance >= amount):
            self.__balance = self.__balance - amount
            self.__numWithdrawals = self.__numWithdrawals + 1
            self.__totalWithdrawals = self.__totalWithdrawals + amount
            return True
        else:
            return False

def main():
    acctlist=[]
    account=input()
    amount=eval(input())
    type=input()

    while(type!='#'):
        if (type=='D'):
            account=input()
            amount=eval(input())
            for i in range(len(acctlist())):
                if (account==acctlist[i].getbankaccount()):
                    index=i
                acctlist[index].Deposit(amount)
                PrintSuccessfullTrans(account, type, amount, acctlist[index].getBalance())
        elif (type=='W'):
            account=input()
            amount=eval(input())
            for i in range(len(acctlist())):
                if (account==acctlist[i].getbankaccount()):
                    index=i
                    status=(acctlist[index].Withdrawal(amount))
                    if (status == True):
                        PrintSuccessfulTrans(account, type, amount, acctlist[index].getbalance())
                    else:
                        PrintDenied(account, type, amount, "<DENIED>")
        elif (type == 'B'):
            type=ConvertType(type)
            amount=eval(input)
            print(acctlist[i].getbankaccount(), amount)
        elif (type == 'T'):
            account1=input()
            account2=input()
            amount=eval(input())
            for i in range(len(acctlist())):
                if (accoun1t==acctlist[i].getbankaccount()):
                    index=i
                    acctlist[index].Deposit(amount)
                    if status == True:
                        print('Test1')
                    else:
                        print('Test2')
            for g in range(len(acctlist())):
                if (account2==acctlist[i].getbankaccount()):
                    index=g
                    acctlist[index].Withdrawal(amount)

        account=input()
        amount=eval(input())
        type=input()


def PrintSuccessfulTrans(account,type, amount, balance):
                typeName = ConvertType(type)
                print("{:8s}{:12}{:8.2f}{:12.2f}".format(account,typeName,amount,balance))


def PrintDenied(account,type,amount, balance):
                typeName = ConvertType(type)
                print("{:8s}{:12}{:8.2f}{:>12}".format(account,typeName,amount,balance))

def ConvertType(type):
                if (type == 'D'):
                    return "Deposit"

                elif (type == 'W'):
                    return "Withdrawal"

                elif (type == 'B'):
                    return "Balance"
main()
```

```
11
ABC123
500
DEF456
1000
XYZ999
2056
MNI612
2012
CKE909
1313
THM115
5783
WBS319
2041
GFL522
10238
JDT121
876
JFL216
9218
GRP904
820
W
JFL216
587.24
D
MNI612
420.45
D
XYZ999
214.38
W
THM115
1045.23
D
WBS319
258.30
W
JDT121
924.10
T
GFL522
JDT121
2000
B
GFL522
0
B
XYZ999
0
T
DEF456
ABC123
50.50
#
#
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is wrong with my inputs because I keep getting a NameError. I'll be more clear in the edit, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing something like this, try invoking python interactively and experimenting a bit:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 12 2013, 16:26:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input()
11
11
>>> input()
ABC123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ABC123' is not defined
```

There you go, first problem replicated.

Presumably you want something like `raw_input()` (or python 3.x, where that's what `input` now does).

Without commenting on everything else, I'll just note here that your dispatch loop also checks for types 'D', 'W', 'B', and 'T', but not '11', 'ABC123', and so on.  Presumably you want to set up the account-list first, and only then handle letter-coded transactions.

Comment: How is it reading it so far? How do I make it check for the first 22 objects then make it start checking for types?

Comment: You have a lot of choices, but if you want to have a single input stream, you could (for instance) read the "database" part up through a first `#`-on-a-line-by-itself, then read the "transactions" part through the next `#`-on-a-line-by-itself.

Comment: Where do I append these inputs if I wanted to?

Comment: What I saw was that your existing input file consists of two sets of "groups of lines".  The first set is always a pair: account-balance (on first line), account-name (on second line).  You can assume that this continues until you reach something different, such as '#' on a line by itself.  You don't even need the '#': the second set begins with the first letter-code (one of D/W/B/T): you could just assume that if it's not one of those, it must be a balance-and-account-name pair.  In fact, you could even allow those two sets to intermingle: 11\nABC123\nW\nABC123\n1.50\n500\nDEF456\n...